# How can I build up my knowledge in particle physics to the level that I can calculate the path of elementary particles in a perfect vacuum?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, beyond-the-standard-model, large-hadron-collider, strong-force

I have to write a research paper (don't know the exact english translation) for school. The question I want the paper to answer/discuss is: 'Can the universe be predicted at sub-atomic level?'

The desired structure of my paper is as follows:

- Introduction
- An example of an accurate prediction, either through the use of an real world experiment or through the use of an hypothetical situation
- Highlighting problems in physics that are currently considered random
- Conclusion

At first, I was planning to use the public data of the LHC for the prediction, but these are experiments happening in the real world - where every law of the universe is in effect, whether we know/have mastery of it or not - and thus a prediction might have inaccuracies that can't be explained. This is why I am planning to draw the image of an perfect vacuum where only the (applicable) laws that are currently known/theorized apply and calculate a path of a few elementary particles.

Issue is, I'm a student in my last year of high school (different school system but I think this is an accurate comparison) and don't have the required knowledge to calculate the forces applied on elementary particles (I had never even heard about strong and weak force).

What books, papers, etc. would you recommend to speed me along to be able to acquire the necessary knowledge?

I'm looking for an learning route to follow (and maybe pick up some sources along the way for my paper). If you're worried about the time required to get up to speed, I'm willing to spend 40-50 hours or more per week working on this.

Thanks in advance <3

Comment: 'Can the universe be predicted at sub-atomic level?' - It cannot be deterministically predicted, as heisenbergs principle of uncertainty states: by measuring the positions of your 'particles', you would change their impulses and vice versa. The answer to the question seems clear, I am sure you will find some literature about these kind of predictability issues that occur in quantum physics

Comment: @finnmglas The kind of predictability issues that you speak of would be something that I would include in the 3rd part of my desired structure. 

This is the first time I hear about the the uncertainty principle, so forgive my confusion, but this is my current understanding: It is impossible to measure the position of a particle without altering the path of the particle and vice versa. The question that rises for me is, is the alteration not calculable?

Comment: Besides that, is it okay for me to skip over the practicality of measuring the momentum and position of a particle? Since I intend to make my paper about the possibility of prediction, rather than applicability.

Comment: The alteration is not deterministically computable, we can only set statistic margins of its trajectory. That's why we take a wave function that basically describes the probability of possible positions along a trajectory.

Comment: Can you tell more about your current education and mathematics knowledge? There are quite few physical approaches to your problem, but to actualy do calculations, I see bigger problem in understanding the mathematics, then physics.

Comment: Elementary particles don’t have a path like you imagine. Lots of things in physics are unpredictable. For example, you can’t know when a particular uranium nucleus is going to radioactively decay. But you can know the half-life and other statistical properties.

Comment: @Vid My current education is the last year of 'vwo' (the required education level to apply for university). Since I am currently in my exam year I thought I'd just give you the subjects covered in my math exam: 
- Formulas, Functions and Charts
- Differential and integral calculus
- Trigonometric functions
- Geometry with coordinates.

Please do tell me if you need more specifics or other info